# Can AJAX be enabled for a form element inside a tableselect row?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

Firstly, a working select element with an AJAX callback:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form['select'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => [
      0 => 'ZERO',
      1 => 'ONE',
      2 => 'TWO',
    ],
    '#ajax' => [
      'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxSelectChanged'],
      'event' => 'change',
    ],
  ];

  $form['submit'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  ];

  return $form;
}

public function ajaxSelectChanged(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $selection = $form_state->getValue('select');
  // Do something with the selection.
}
```

Now I want to put the select element inside a tableselect element...

[This comment](https://api.drupal.org/comment/62637#comment-62637) shows how form elements may be added inside the rows of a tableselect (which is also a form element).

Here's my attempt:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  // Build the sortable table header.
  $select_options = [
    0 => 'ZERO',
    1 => 'ONE',
    2 => 'TWO',
  ];

  $form['table'] = [
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => [
      'name' => $this->t('Name'),
      'select' => $this->t('Select'),
    ],
    '#options' => [
      'alice' => [
        'name' => $this->t('Alice'),
        'select' => [
          'data' => [
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#options' => $select_options,
            '#ajax' => [
              'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxSelectChanged'],
              'event' => 'change',
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
      'bob' => [
        'name' => $this->t('Bob'),
        'select' => [
          'data' => [
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#options' => $select_options,
            '#ajax' => [
              'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxSelectChanged'],
              'event' => 'change',
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ],
    '#empty' => $this->t('There is nothing to see here.'),
  ];

  $form['submit'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  ];

  return $form;
}

public function ajaxSelectChanged(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $selection = $form_state->getValues();
  // Do something with the selection.
}
```

It works, except for the AJAX callback, which never runs.

[image: Tableselect AJAX Form]

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there a way to let form elements inside a table trigger AJAX callbacks when they are changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `#ajax` doesn't work for your tableselect options is that the render array is inside a render attribute - render attributes are not processed as render element children.

That means that they don't receive an ID, or a name. And that the [`RenderElement::preRenderAjaxForm`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21RenderElement.php/function/RenderElement%3A%3ApreRenderAjaxForm/8.3.x) does not process them.

There are several ways to circumvent this problem.

Option 1: Create a hidden ajax elements below the table and trigger them via ajax.
Option 2: Run the required processing yourself.

Here is a sample implementation of Option 2:

```
class SandboxForm extends FormBase {
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'sandbox';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Build the sortable table header.
    $select_options = [
      0 => 'ZERO',
      1 => 'ONE',
      2 => 'TWO',
    ];

    $form['table'] = [
      '#type' => 'tableselect',
      '#header' => [
        'name' => $this->t('Name'),
        'select' => $this->t('Select'),
      ],
      '#empty' => $this->t('There is nothing to see here.'),
      '#options' => [
        'alice' => [
          'name' => $this->t('Alice'),
          'select' => [
            'data' => [
              '#type' => 'select',
              '#options' => $select_options,
              '#ajax' => [
                'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxSelectChanged'],
                'event' => 'change',
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
        'bob' => [
          'name' => $this->t('Bob'),
          'select' => [
            'data' => [
              '#type' => 'select',
              '#options' => $select_options,
              '#ajax' => [
                'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxSelectChanged'],
                'event' => 'change',
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
      '#process' => [
        '::processTable',
        [Tableselect::class, 'processTableselect']
      ]
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Submit'),
      '#ajax' => [
        'wrapper' => 'test',
        'callback' => [static::class, 'ajaxSelectChanged'],
      ],
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function processTable(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
    foreach (array_keys($element['#options']) as $option) {
      foreach (array_keys($element['#options'][$option]) as $col) {
        if (is_array($element['#options'][$option][$col]) && isset($element['#options'][$option][$col]['data'])) {
          $element['#options'][$option][$col]['data']['#name'] = implode('-', [$element['#name'], $option, $col]);
          $element['#options'][$option][$col]['data']['#id'] = implode('-', [$element['#id'], $option, $col]);
          $element['#options'][$option][$col]['data'] = RenderElement::preRenderAjaxForm($element['#options'][$option][$col]['data']);
        }
      }
    }
    return $element;
  }

  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::validateForm($form, $form_state); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
  }


  public static function ajaxSelectChanged(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $selection = $form_state->getValue('select');
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $selection = $form_state->getValue('select');
  }

}
```

P.S.

I know that for regular `table` elements you can pass render array by not using the `#rows` attribute and passing them as children. I tried it here and it failed, though I could be missing something.

Comment: This works! However, it also triggers the first (enabled) submit button on the outer form. Can that be prevented? If it's a long answer, I'll ask in a separate question.

Comment: Because this is a core problem with Drupal tableselect, any solution would be some kind of hack and might cause these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

- Add placeholders (like a simple string, or an empty array) to the table row, where the select lists should go.
- Add select lists below the table, and check that they have fully functional AJAX callbacks.
- Register a `#pre_render` function on the form which moves the select lists into the table.

In the buildForm function:

```
$form['#pre_render'] = [[$this, 'preRender']];
```

And then in the form class:

```
public static function preRender(array $form) {
  foreach ($form['table']['#options'] as $delta => &$row) {
    $row['select_lists']['data'] = $form['select_lists'][$delta];
    unset($form['select_lists'][$delta]);
  }
  return $form;
}
```

I also tried `hook_form_alter`, but it runs too early, and messes up the AJAX. Apparently, a `pre_render` function runs after the AJAX stuff has been set up by Drupal, and then we can move the element anywhere on the page without affecting the AJAX functionality.